# MVC5 injecting dependency on a view with castle windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, asp.net-mvc-5

Consider the following scenario

I have a MVC5. I would like to have a base view with some dependencies as:

```
public class BasicView<T> : WebViewPage<T>                             
{        
    public IResourceService ResourceService { get; set; }       

    public override void Execute()
    {

    }
}
```

Then in the webconfig....

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />  
    <pages pageBaseType="BasicView">
```

The property is never injected :(

when I use the same dependency on a regular constructor, works without problems.

What am I missing here? Windsort documentation says the container will try to resolve that kind of Properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windsor does not inject into your views because it does not own the view creation process.

You have to use Windsor as service locator in this scenario. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21129937/19892) to find out how to use it.