# castle windsor - No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have `FileHandler.ashx` file in my main project.

```
public class FileHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    private readonly IAccountService _accountService;
    private readonly IAttachmentService _attachmentService;


    public FileHandler(IAccountService accountService, IAttachmentService attachmentService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
        _attachmentService = attachmentService;
    }

  ....
}
```

Also, I have `HandlerInstaller`:

```
public class HandlersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                        .Where(Component.IsInSameNamespaceAs<FileHandler>())
                        .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
                        .LifestyleSingleton());

    }
}
```

But when I try to call file `FileHandler.ashx` I get an error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

What is the reason? how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have a dependency resolver for your webpages? Don't know how it works with ashx, but in mvc/web.api you have to set a new dependency resolver to support ctors with parameters; http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver

Comment: Can you provide more code/details? how do you attach the container to your project? Do you have registration for the services which FileHandler depends on? Are you sure it is this class that introduces the exception? (i also don't know how ashx works)

Comment: Do this: http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/11/windsor-managed-httpmodules.html but for HttpHandlers instead of HttpModules.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to provide an empty construtor like that

```
public class FileHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        private readonly IAccountService _accountService;
        private readonly IAttachmentService _attachmentService;

        public FileHandler()
        {
        }
        public FileHandler(IAccountService accountService, IAttachmentService attachmentService)
        {
            _accountService = accountService;
            _attachmentService = attachmentService;
        }

      ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that Castle Windsor can't resolve the dependencies that your current constructor requires `IAccountService` and `IAttachmentService`.

In this case it is probably looking for a parameterless one instead to use.

Make sure the above dependencies are registered and windsor can resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config do you have this:

```
  <castle>
    <installers>
      <install type="Your.Namespace.HandlersInstaller, Your.Namespace" />
    </installers>
  </castle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Castle Windsor does not know how to create `IHttpHandler` instances. There is not somethig like `ControlerFactory` for handlers, so you cant intercept the handler creation process. You have two options:

1. Implement your handlers as controller actions and use standard `WindsorControlerFactory` to inject your dependencies.
2. Provide parameter less constructor with Windsor used as service locator:

   ```
   public class FileHandler : IHttpHandler
   {
      readonly IAccountService accountService;
      readonly IAttachmentService attachmentService;

     public FileHandler()
     {
       var containerAccessor = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance as IContainerAccessor;
       var container = conatinerAccessor.Container;
       accountService = container.Resolve<IAccountService>();
       attachmentService = container.Resolve<IAttachmentService>();
     }

     public FileHandler(IAccountService accountService, IAttachmentService attachmentService)
     {
       this.accountService = accountService;
       this.attachmentService = attachmentService;
     }

     ...
   }
   ```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21129937/19892) to find out how to implement `IContainerAccessor`.